# install portmidi library

Tags: java

I am trying to install the portmidi library: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/portmedia/wiki/Installing%20portmidi%20on%20Linux

I have followed the instructions, but when i do "make", I get this message below. I have tried different Javapaths, i dont know if it is right now. Can somebody tell me what is going wrong here ?

```
natanael@natanael-iMac:~/workspace/portmidi$ make
-- JAVA_JVM_LIB_PATH is 
-- JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH is /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include
-- JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 is /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include/linux
-- JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY is /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/natanael/workspace/portmidi
[ 93%] Built target pmjni
[ 93%] Built target portmidi-static
[ 93%] Built target latency
[ 93%] Built target midiclock
[ 93%] Built target midithread
[ 93%] Built target midithru
[ 93%] Built target mm
[ 93%] Built target qtest
[ 93%] Built target sysex
[ 93%] Built target test
[ 93%] Built target portmidi-dynamic
[ 93%] Generating pmdefaults/PmDefaults.class
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /home/natanael/workspace/portmidi/pm_java/pm_java
make[2]: *** [pm_java/pmdefaults/PmDefaults.class] Fehler 2
make[1]: *** [pm_java/CMakeFiles/pmdefaults_target.dir/all] Fehler 2
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
natanael@natanael-iMac:~/workspace/portmidi$
```

Thanks !

Comment: Just ran into the same issue. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, one of the `Makefile`s generated by `ccmake` is broken. I was able to fix the issue by running

```
sed -i 's/pm_java\/pm_java/pm_java/' build.make
```

in the `pm_java/CMakeFiles/pmdefaults_target.dir/` subdirectory of the project *after* running `ccmake .` (on Ubuntu, though). (The `sed` command replaces all occurrences of `pm_java/pm_java` by `pm_java`.)

Everything compiles, and I can even run `pmdefaults` from the `Release` directory using

```
java -Djava.library.path=. -jar pmdefaults.jar
```

Comment: This worked on the Debian "wheezy" distribution as well.