# What does this linking error mean when installing portmidi?

Tags: c, cmake

After I configured the cmake file for portmidi, and proceeded to use make to make the necessary files, I encountered this error during compilation:

```
- Build files have been written to: /home/mycomputername

/Desktop/portmedia/portmidi
[  2%] Linking C shared library /Release/libpmjni.so
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot open output file /Release/libpmjni.so: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
pm_common/CMakeFiles/pmjni.dir/build.make:251: recipe for target '/Release/libpmjni.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/Release/libpmjni.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:87: recipe for target 'pm_common/CMakeFiles/pmjni.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [pm_common/CMakeFiles/pmjni.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm quite confused. I've tried to insert the flags -fpic in the cxx-flags section of ccmake and change the default java install paths to no avail. Quite frankly, I think it has to do with the messing up of execution order, but I don't know where.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the Release dir exits? I guess you're using uninitialized macro for some root dir...

Comment: what is the location of /Release/libpmjni.so in your system.

Comment: There isn’t a Release/libpmjni.so in my system. There’s only the pmjni.c code as far as I can tell.

Comment: Well. I didn’t write this code. Dunno what’s happening honestly, much less find an uninitialised macro. I am also never given the cmakelists.txt file for cmake in the installation package. I should just go over the source... though I’m not that familiar with c...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there was some configuring to do in the directories that CMake points to in ccmake configuration. I just redownloaded the files and unzipped it into a newly made portmedia directory. Also, to make sure that you don't get any hiccups in making pm_defaults, refer to [Nate's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127821/install-portmidi-library). To quote:

> Apparently, one of the `Makefile`s generated by `ccmake` is broken. I was able to fix the issue by running
>
> ```
> sed -i 's/pm_java\/pm_java/pm_java/' build.make
> ```
>
> in the `pm_java/CMakeFiles/pmdefaults_target.dir/` subdirectory of the
>   project *after* running `ccmake .` (on Ubuntu, though). (The `sed`
>   command replaces all occurrences of `pm_java/pm_java` by `pm_java`.)
>
> Everything compiles, and I can even run `pmdefaults` from the
>   `Release` directory using
>
> ```
> java -Djava.library.path=. -jar pmdefaults.jar
> ```